# Unable to read payload from File

Tags: java, automation, rest-assured, payload

i am trying to insert payload from jsonfile but getting an bad request and unable to read date from the file , not sure what i am doing wrong

```
File jsonBody =new File(".\\JSONFileinput\\file.json");
        Response resp=given().header("Content-Type","application/json")
        
        .body(jsonBody)
        .log()
        .all()
        .post("https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com/booking");

    
    resp.prettyPrint();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jackson objectMapper
objectMapper.writeValue(new File(".\JSONFileinput\file.json"), jsonBody);
or writeValueAsString

Answer (score 0):

Read json as a String and the pass it to your body:

```
String payload = Files.readString(".\\JSONFileinput\\file.json", StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
```